# What patterns are people using for hosting Web Forms application in Windows Containers?

Tags: docker, docker-container, windows-container

What is the best practice for hosting legacy ASP.NET web form applications in Windows Containers?

One image per web app?
Compiled web apps mounted into a container of the ASPNET image at docker run?

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope. It is specifically mentioned as being inappropriate here in the [help/dont-ask]: *If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.*

Comment: There is a pretty interesting two part blog on [Dockerizing Nerd Dinner](https://blog.sixeyed.com/dockerizing-nerd-dinner-part-1-running-a-legacy-asp-net-app-in-a-windows-container/). That's probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

For each application e.g. asp.net application, web service you would have a docker image somewhere in your private registry e.g. azure container registry. After building all your images, you need orchestration between all of containers from these images. For example, you can use yaml file to define all your services and using docker compose bring up your application with all its dependencies. [Here](http://passionatecoder.ca/Article/Deploying-ASPNET-and-SQL-SERVER-application-using-Windows-Containers-on-Azure) is an example if this.